# Failed to read configuration file from @PropertySource on JBoss-EAP-64

Tags: java, spring, jboss, websphere, jboss6.x

I am trying to run my application on JBoss EAP-6.4, but I am getting the following error:

```
17:29:27,353 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.xxx.yyy.appname.Config]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [git.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
17:29:27,369 ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.xxx.yyy.appname.Config]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [git.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181) [spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
```

This is strange because the application works without problems on WebSphere 8.5.5 and reads parameters from the configuration file without any problems.
The file `git.properties` is placed under: `src/main/webapp` directory in the project. 
This is the configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml"})
@PropertySource("classpath:git.properties")
@ComponentScan("com.myapplication.controller")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

I have read [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html), but I still do not know what is going on and what may be wrong.

Comment: classpath:git.properties does not exist in your working space. Double check it

Comment: @Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn this is not the classpath but the file name. WebSphere does not have problems with it, so why JBoss?

Comment: Your `classpath` does not refer to the same directory (`src/main/webapp`). You have a correct `classpath` in `applicationContext.xml` file, try to deduce `git.properties` from that path

Answer (score 0):

I managed it in this way, that I moved the file to `\src\main\resources\git.properties` location, 
and added `/` here:
`@PropertySource("classpath:/git.properties")`.

I still do not understand why, but it now works on both JBoss and WebSphere.